# Polymorphism and overriding a method from a class template in C++

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, overriding

I would like to have a class template with basic implementations of my methods, and a set of subclasses that use the template class with particular types (double, int, char*) and override some subset of those base implementations, as needed. However, my overridden methods don't seem to get called unless I declare the object as an instance of the subclass. In exploring this problem I came up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual void print1 (T thing) {
        std::cout << "Base print1: " << thing << std::endl;
    }

    virtual void print2 (T thing) {
        std::cout << "Base print2: " << thing << std::endl;
    }
};

class IntClass : public BaseClass<int> {
public:
    void print2 (int thing) {
        std::cout << "Int print2: " << thing << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    BaseClass<int> thing = IntClass();
    thing.print1(1);
    thing.print2(1);

    IntClass thing2 = IntClass();
    thing2.print1(2);
    thing2.print2(2);

    return 0;
}
```

My expected output would be:

```
Base print1: 1
Int print2: 1
Base print1: 2
Int print2: 2
```

But instead, I get:

```
Base print1: 1
Base print2: 1
Base print1: 2
Int print2: 2
```

Is it possible to achieve my goal here, or am I better off creating separate base classes for each type in this case?  Apologies if my terminology is a bit off - I am relatively new to C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type of `thing` is `BaseClass<int>`, not `IntClass`. The temporary `IntClass` you used to initialise it has been destroyed, after copying the `BaseClass` sub-object. Copying part of an object like this is sometimes known as *slicing*.

Polymorphism works when you use references or pointers to a base class, which may refer to an object of a derived class. So you'd get the expected result with a reference to an `IntClass` object:

```
// In C++11 or later, you can bind an rvalue reference to a temporary, extending its lifetime
BaseClass<int> && thing = IntClass();

// If you're stuck in the past, you can bind an lvalue reference to a variable
IntClass ic;
BaseClass<int> & thing = ic;
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But I am having trouble getting your suggested line of code to work.  Am I missing something?  `error: expected unqualified-id before && token`

Comment: @diagonalfish: If you've got an ancient compiler, or haven't specified a C++11 or C++14 dialect, then it might not know what an *rvalue* reference is. In that case, you could try `IntClass ic; BaseClass<int> & thing = ic;` or faff around with dynamic allocation as another answer suggests.

Comment: Aha, yep, -std=c++11 did it.  Awesome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`BaseClass<int> thing = IntClass();`

This doesn't do what you think it does. It creates a temporary instance of `IntClass` and then copies it into `thing` which is of type `BaseClass<int>`. The result is called object-slicing (you can search for that).

In this case, as the derived type is known at compile-time, there's no reason not to use `IntClass` as the type of `thing`. But for general usage, you need to use pointers. Here is an example:

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseClass<int>> thing(new IntClass);
thing->print1(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were to use a pointer, you would achieve your expected results. But, as short research for this answer has learned me, what has happened here is that 'thing' -- the object called thing; not the parameter, takes the part of IntClass that is of BaseClass and simply discards the rest. This is called object slicing.